# Python setup config install_requires "good practices"

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

My question here may seem really naive but I never found any clue about it on web resources.

The question is, concerning `install_requires` argument for `setup()` function or `setup.cfg` file, **is it a good practice to mention *every* package used, even python built-in ones such as `os` for example ?**

One can assume that any python environment has those common packages, so is it problematic to explicitly mention them in the setup, making it potentially over-verbose ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it gets much clear now !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`install_requires` should include non-standard library requirements, and constraints on their versions (as needed).

For example, this would declare minimal versions for `numpy` and `scipy`, but allow any version of `scikit-learn`:

```py
setup(
  # ...
  install_requires=["numpy>=1.13.3", "scipy>=0.19.1", "scikit-learn"]
)
```

Packages such as `os`, `sys` are part of Python's standard library, so should not be included.

- As @sinoroc mentioned, only **direct** 3rd party dependencies should be declared here. *Dependencies-of-your-dependencies* are handled automatically. (For example, `scikit-learn` depends on `joblib`; when the former is required, the latter will be installed).
- A list of standard library packages are listed here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/

---

I've found it helpful to read other packages and see how their `setup.py` files are defined.

- [`imbalanced-learn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/edd75224a3ecfa043f6971f81e2c7073cb08db30/setup.py#L38-L43)
- [`pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/122d50246bcffcf8c3f252146340ac02676a5bf6/setup.py#L716-L719)

Answer (score 5):

You should list ***top-level 3rd party dependencies***.

- Don't list packages and modules from Python's standard library.
- Do list 3rd party dependencies your code directly depends on, i.e. the projects containing:

  - the packages and modules your code imports;
  - the binaries your code directly calls (in subprocesses for example).
- Don't list dependencies of your dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

`install_requires` should mention only packages that don't come prepackaged with the standard library.

If you're afraid some package might not be included due to Python versioning, you can specify that your packages requires a python version bigger or equal to X.

Note: That packaging python packages is a notoriously hairy thing.

I'd recommend you take a look at [pyproject.toml](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0631/), these can be pip installed like any normal package and are used by some of the more modern tools like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/)

Comment: _PEP 631_ is not relevant here as of today. It is not implemented yet by any tool that I know of.